# How to set notification sound duration in the right way android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm new in android. And I'm trying to create a notification with custom sound duration. I've seen a lot of apps whith this function but I can't understand how to make it in the most usefull way.

For my notification I use `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class NotificationAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

setNotification(context);

}

 private void setNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context).
            setTicker("Hi!").
            setAutoCancel(true).
            setContentTitle("Bla bla lba!").
            setContentText("Hi hi!").
            setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
            setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution which works great for me

So you should start a thread which sleeps as much time as you need and then replaces your current notification with the same one but without any sound/vibration ect.

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(duration * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notificationManager.cancel(id);

                //start the same notification without sound
                soundlessNotification(context);
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any way to control the sound duration but you can mute the AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION using below code:-

```
final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true or false);
```

don't forget to unmute it after the notification sound total duration is elapsed.